# If $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}f(x) = L \neq 0$ must it be that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \sin x $ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

I got this question:

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that satisfies $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}f(x) = L \neq 0$, Must it be that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) sin x $ does not exist?

I tried to prove it and to find a counter example but I failed so far.

Answer (score 4):

If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L$, with $L\ne 0$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(2n\pi x)=L$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(2n\pi x+\pi/2)=L.$$
But 
$$
f(2n\pi x)\sin(2n\pi )=0,
$$
and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(2n\pi x)\sin(2\pi n)=0$, while
$$
f(2n\pi x+\pi/2)\sin(2n\pi+\pi/2)=f(2n\pi x+\pi/2)\to L,
$$
as $n\to\infty$, and hence the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\sin x$$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the sequence $x_n=\pi/2+n\pi$